# Find integer solutions for $\frac{3+2^{r_{1}}}{3-2(-1)^{r_{0}}+6m_{0}}=\frac{3+2^{r_{0}}}{3-2(-1)^{r_{1}}+6m_{1}}=2^{r_{0}+r_{1}}-9$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the integer solutions, or prove none exist, for $r_{0}$ and $r_{1}$ in the following equations (it is not necessary to find $m_{0}$ and $m_{1}$ but they would be nice as well):

$\frac{3+2^{r_{1}}}{3-2(-1)^{r_{0}}+6m_{0}}=\frac{3+2^{r_{0}}}{3-2(-1)^{r_{1}}+6m_{1}}=2^{r_{0}+r_{1}}-9$

Any $r_{i} \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and $m_{i} \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}\cup\{0\}$ for $i \in \{0,1 \}$

I've tried to use modular arithmetic in with mod(6) to try to reduce the fractions, but it didn't seem to yield any restrictions or useful information. Any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about

$$\frac{3+2^{r_{1}}}{3-2(-1)^{r_{0}}+6m_{0}}=\frac{3+2^{r_{0}}}{3-2(-1)^{r_{1}}+6m_{1}}=2^{r_{0}+r_{1}}-9 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The only set of set solutions is $r_0 = r_1 = 2$ and $m_0 = m_1 = 0$ since all $3$ values become $7$. As for determining this is the case, note the denominators in \eqref{eq1A} are always positive integers since $3 - 2(-1)^{r_i}$ is either $1$ or $5$ and $6m_i$ is non-negative, so the results will be at most $3 + 2^{r_i}$. Also, the right side value of $2^{r_0 + r_1} - 9$ is larger than $3 + 2^{r_i}$ for the smaller $r_i$, say $r_0$, if $2^{r_0 + r_1} - 9 \gt 3 + 2^{r_0} \implies 2^{r_0}\left(2^{r_1} - 1\right) \gt 12$ if $r_0 \gt 2$ or $r_1 \gt 3$. This means there are only a few values you need to check manually. Also, for the right side to be positive requires $r_0 + r_1 \ge 4$. Thus, the only cases to check are $r_0 = r_1 = 2$, which gives the solution I mention, and $r_0 = 2$ and $r_1 = 3$, which doesn't work since the right side becomes $2^{5} - 9 = 32 - 9 = 23$, but $3 + 2^{2} = 7$ and $3 + 2^{3} = 11$ only.

Comment: I follow up until you say $2^{r_{0}+r_{1}}-9 > 3+2^{r_{0}}$. I reasoned that because of the denominator, being 1 or greater, on $3+2^{r_{i}}$ will restrict the RHS to yield $2^{r_{0}+r_{1}}-9 \leq 3+2^{r_{0}}$ and $2^{r_{0}}(2^{r_{1}}-1) \leq 12$ thus placing an upper bound on the values of $r_{i}$. The necessity of the RHS to be positive places the lower bound on $r_{i}$ thus yielding $r_{0}=r_{1}=2$ as the only solution. Is this correct?

Comment: @JosephSchmidt That statement was to indicate that when the $r_0$ and $r_1$ values are too large, the RHS becomes larger than the LHS and, thus, there's no chance of them being equal. Your reasoning is approaching it as saying there's an upper limit, which is effectively the same as what I'm stating. As such, it's also correct.